# Back Propagation Implementation in Python for Deep Neural Network

Tags: python, neural-network

I have coded Back Propagation algorithm for Deep neural network from scratch, which runs pretty fine. Gradient Check does not seem to produce any error, however, the cost does not seem to decrease, any recommendation to improve the convergence of code?

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import h5py
import sys


def relu(z):
    a = np.maximum(0,z)
    assert(a.shape == z.shape)
    return a

def sigmoid(z):
    a = 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
    assert( a.shape == z.shape)
    return a

def initalize_parameters(layers_dim):
    """n_x is the dimension of input data, n_y is dimension of output dat,n_h size of hidden layers"""
    #np.random.seed(3)
    parameters = {} # dictionary used to store the parameters
    L = len(layers_dim)
    for i in range(L-2):
        parameters["W"+ str(i+1)] = np.random.randn(layers_dim[i+1], layers_dim[i]) # * np.sqrt(np.divide(2,layers_dim[i]))  # he initialization for relu
        parameters["b"+str(i+1)] = np.zeros((layers_dim[i+1], 1))
        assert (parameters["W" + str(i+1)].shape == (layers_dim[i+1], layers_dim[i]))
        assert (parameters["b" + str(i+1)].shape == (layers_dim[i+1], 1))
    parameters["W" + str(L-1)] = np.random.randn(layers_dim[L-1], layers_dim[L - 2])# * np.sqrt(np.divide(1, layers_dim[L - 2]))  #he initialization, to avoid vanishing and exploding gradieints
    parameters["b" + str(L-1)] = np.zeros((layers_dim[L-1], 1))
    assert (parameters["W" + str(L-1)].shape == (layers_dim[L-1], layers_dim[L - 2]))
    assert (parameters["b" + str(L-1)].shape == (layers_dim[L-1], 1))
    return parameters


def forward_linear(A, W, b):
    """ This function returns the linear combination: Z"""
    Z= np.dot(W,A)+b
    cache=(A, W, b)
    assert(Z.shape == (W.shape[0], A.shape[1]))
    return Z,cache

def forward_linear_activation(A_prev, W, b, activation):
    Z,linear_cache = forward_linear(A_prev, W, b)
    if activation == "sigmoid":
        A = sigmoid(Z)
    if activation == "relu":
        A = relu(Z)
    activation_cache = Z
    assert(A.shape == (W.shape[0], A_prev.shape[1]))
    cache=(linear_cache, activation_cache)
    return A,cache

def L_layer_forward_activation(X,parameters):
    caches = []
    NumberLayers = len(parameters)//2
    A = X
    for i in range(1,NumberLayers):
        A_prev=A
        A, cache = forward_linear_activation(A_prev,parameters["W"+str(i)],parameters["b"+str(i)],'relu')
        caches.append(cache)
    AL,cache = forward_linear_activation(A, parameters["W"+str(NumberLayers)],parameters["b"+str(NumberLayers)], "sigmoid")
    caches.append(cache)
    assert(AL.shape==(1,X.shape[1]))
    return AL, caches


def backward_sigmoid(dA, activation_cache ):
    Z = activation_cache
    A = sigmoid(Z)
    gZ_prime = np.multiply(A,(1 - A))
    dZ = np.multiply(dA,gZ_prime)
    assert(dZ.shape == activation_cache.shape)
    assert(gZ_prime.shape == activation_cache.shape)
    return dZ, gZ_prime


def backward_relu(dA, activation_cache):
    gZ_prime = np.int64(activation_cache>0)
    dZ =  np.multiply(dA, np.int64(activation_cache > 0))
    assert(gZ_prime.shape == dA.shape)
    assert(dZ.shape == dA.shape )
    return dZ, gZ_prime

def backward_linear(dZ,lmbda, linear_cache):
    """This function will translate dz linearly from one layer to another. Here cache comes from def forward_linear(A,W,b):
    """
    A_prev, W, b = linear_cache
    m= A_prev.shape[1]           #number of training data
    dW = 1/m * np.dot(dZ,A_prev.T) + np.multiply(lmbda / m , W,dtype= np.float64)
    db = 1/m * np.sum(dZ,axis=1,dtype=np.float64,keepdims=True)
    dA_prev = np.dot(W.T, dZ)
    assert(dW.shape == W.shape)
    assert(db.shape == b.shape)
    assert(dA_prev.shape == A_prev.shape)
    return dW, db, dA_prev


def backward_activation(dA,cache,lmbda,activation):
    """This function estimates dZ from dA obtained using backward_linear"""
    linear_cache, activation_cache= cache             # cache for any given layers
    Z = activation_cache
    if activation == "sigmoid":
        dZ, g = backward_sigmoid(dA, Z)                #sigmoid derivative
        dW, db, dA_prev = backward_linear(dZ, lmbda, linear_cache)
    elif activation == "relu":
        dZ, g = backward_relu(dA, Z)
        dW, db, dA_prev = backward_linear(dZ, lmbda,linear_cache)
    else:
        print("Error!! enter the correct activation function")

    return dW, db, dA_prev

def L_backward_propagation(AL,Y,caches,lmbda):
    """ This part of the code does the full backward propagation"""
    grad={}
    L = len(caches)                                                             # Number of layers in the ANN
    Y= Y.reshape(AL.shape)
    ##################################################
    dAL = -(np.divide(Y, AL) - np.divide((1 - Y), (1 - AL)))
    cache = caches[L-1]
    dW, db, dA_prev = backward_activation(dAL,cache,lmbda,"sigmoid")
    #################################
    grad["dA"+str(L)] = dA_prev
    grad["dW" + str(L)] = dW
    grad["db" + str(L)] = db
    for i in reversed(range(L-1)):
        cache=caches[i]
        dW, db, dA_prev = backward_activation(grad["dA"+str(i+2)],cache,lmbda,"relu")
        grad["dA"+str(i+1)] = dA_prev
        grad["dW" + str(i+1)] = dW
        grad["db" + str(i+1)] = db    

    return grad
#####################################################################################
##########################################################################################
def parameter_update(grad,learning_rate,parameters):
    """This function updates the paramters"""    
    L = len(parameters) //2
    for i in range(L):
        parameters["W" + str(i+1)] = parameters["W" + str(i+1)] - learning_rate * grad["dW" + str(i+1)]
        parameters["b" + str(i+1)] = parameters["b" + str(i+1)] - learning_rate * grad["db" + str(i+1)]
    return parameters
############################################################################################
def initialize_momentum(parameters):
    """ Initializes the first momentum"""
    momentum={}
    L= len(parameters) //2
    for i in range(L):
        momentum["dW" +str(i+1)] = np.zeros(parameters["W" + str(i+1)].shape)
        momentum["db" + str(i+1)] = np.zeros(parameters["b" + str(i+1)].shape)
        ###############################################################################
        assert(momentum["dW" +str(i+1)].shape == parameters["W" +str(i+1)].shape)
        assert(momentum["db" +str(i+1)].shape == parameters["b" +str(i+1)].shape)
    return momentum
########################################################################################
def initialize_s_momentum(parameters):
    """Initializes the second momentum of weights"""
    s_momentum={}
    L= len(parameters)//2
    for i in range(L):
        s_momentum["dW" +str(i+1)] = np.zeros(parameters["W" + str(i+1)].shape)
        s_momentum["db" +str(i+1)] = np.zeros(parameters["b" + str(i+1)].shape)
        assert(s_momentum["dW" +str(i+1)].shape == parameters["W" +str(i+1)].shape)
        assert(s_momentum["db" +str(i+1)].shape == parameters["b" +str(i+1)].shape)
    return s_momentum

def parameter_update_momentum(parameters,grad, momentum, learning_rate,beta):
    """This optimization algorithm uses Gradient descent with momentum to optimize the parameters"""    
    L = len(grad) // 3  # 3 because grad consists of dA, dW , db
    for i in range(L):
        momentum["dW" +str(i+1)] = beta * momentum["dW" +str(i+1)] + (1-beta) * grad["dW" + str(i+1)]
        momentum["db" +str(i+1)] = beta * momentum["db" +str(i+1)] + (1-beta) * grad["db" + str(i+1)]

        parameters["W" + str(i+1)] = parameters["W" + str(i+1)] - learning_rate * momentum["dW" +str(i+1)]
        parameters["b" + str(i+1)] = parameters["b" + str(i+1)] - learning_rate * momentum["db" +str(i+1)]

    return parameters, momentum

def RMS_prop_update(parameters, grad, momentum, learning_rate, beta):
    epsilon = np.float64(1e-8)
    L= len(grad) // 3
    for i in range(L):
        s_momentum["dW" + str(i+1)] = beta * s_momentum["dW" + str(i+1)] + (1-beta) * np.square(grad["dW" +str(i + 1)])
        s_momentum["db" + str(i+1)] = beta * s_momentum["db" + str(i+1)] + (1-beta) * np.square(grad["db" +str(i + 1)])

        parameters["W" +str(i+1)] = parameters["W" +str(i+1)] - learning_rate * np.divide(grad["dW" + str(i+1)], (np.sqrt(s_momentum["dW" +str(i+1)]) +epsilon))
        parameters["b" +str(i+1)] = parameters["b" +str(i+1)] - learning_rate * np.divide(grad["db" + str(i+1)], (np.sqrt(s_momentum["db" +str(i+1)]) +epsilon))

    return parameters, s_momentum       



def adam_algorithm(parameters, grad, momentum,s_momentum,learning_rate, beta1, beta2,t):
    "beta1, beta2 are the exponential decay rates for moment estimates"
    L= len(grad) // 3
    epsilon = 1e-8

    for i in range(L):
        momentum["dW"] = beta1 * momentum["dW" + str(i+1)] + (1-beta1) * grad["dW" + str(i+1)]
        momentum["db"] = beta1 * momentum["db" + str(i+1)] + (1-beta1) * grad["db" + str(i+1)]        
        momentum["dW"] = np.divide(momentum["dW"] , (1- beta1**t))
        momentum["db"] = np.divide(momentum["db"] , (1- beta1**t))

        s_momentum["dW" +str(i+1)] = beta2 * s_momentum["dW" + str(i+1)] + (1- beta2) * np.square(grad["dW" + str(i+1)])
        s_momentum["db" +str(i+1)] = beta2 * s_momentum["db" + str(i+1)] + (1- beta2) * np.square(grad["db" + str(i+1)])
        s_momentum["dW" +str(i+1)] = np.divide(s_momentum["dW"+str(i+1)] , (1- beta2**t))
        s_momentum["db" +str(i+1)] = np.divide(s_momentum["db"+str(i+1)] , (1- beta2**t))

        learning_rate_t = learning_rate * np.divide(np.sqrt(1- beta2 ** t), (1- beta1**t))                            # from Adams paper, increases efficiency   

        parameters["W" +str(i+1)] = parameters["W" +str(i+1)] - learning_rate_t * np.divide(momentum["dW" + str(i+1)], (np.sqrt(s_momentum["dW" +str(i+1)]) +epsilon))
        parameters["b" +str(i+1)] = parameters["b" +str(i+1)] - learning_rate_t * np.divide(momentum["db" + str(i+1)], (np.sqrt(s_momentum["db" +str(i+1)]) +epsilon))
    return parameters, momentum, s_momentum  




def predict(X, parameters):
    AL,_ = L_layer_forward_activation(X,parameters)
    Y_prediction = np.zeros(AL.shape)
    for i in range(AL.shape[1]):
        if AL[0, i] > 0.5:
            Y_prediction[0, i] = 1
        else:
            Y_prediction[0, i] = 0
    assert (Y_prediction.shape == AL.shape)
    return Y_prediction


def load_dataset():
    train_dataset = h5py.File('train_catvnoncat.h5', "r")
    train_set_x_orig = np.array(train_dataset["train_set_x"][:])  # your train set features
    train_set_y_orig = np.array(train_dataset["train_set_y"][:])  # your train set labels
    test_dataset = h5py.File('test_catvnoncat.h5', "r")
    test_set_x_orig = np.array(test_dataset["test_set_x"][:])  # your test set features
    test_set_y_orig = np.array(test_dataset["test_set_y"][:])  # your test set labels
    classes = np.array(test_dataset["list_classes"][:])  # the list of classes
    train_set_y_orig = train_set_y_orig.reshape((1, train_set_y_orig.shape[0]))
    test_set_y_orig = test_set_y_orig.reshape((1, test_set_y_orig.shape[0]))
    return train_set_x_orig, train_set_y_orig, test_set_x_orig, test_set_y_orig, classes

def cost_function(AL, Y ):
    """Unregularized cost function"""
    m =  Y.shape[1]
    cost = -1/m * (np.dot(Y,np.log(AL.T)) + np.dot((1-Y),np.log(1-AL.T)))
    cost = np.squeeze(cost)
    assert(cost.shape ==())
    return cost
def compute_cost_regularization(AL,Y,parameters,lmbda):
    """Returns regularized cost function"""
    m= Y.shape[1]
    cost = -1.0 / m * (np.dot(Y,np.log(AL.T)) + np.dot((1-Y),np.log(1-AL.T)))
    L = len(parameters)//2
    regularization_value = 0
    for i in range(L):
        regularization_value = regularization_value + np.sum(np.square(parameters["W" +str(i+1)]),dtype= np.float64)
    cost_regularization = cost + lmbda / (2*m) * regularization_value
    cost_regularization= np.squeeze(cost_regularization)
    assert(cost_regularization.shape == ())
    return cost_regularization

def Gradient_check(X,Y, parameters, gradients, epsilon,layers_dims,lmbda):
   # parameters: Estimated set of parameters estimated using Back-Propagation
   # gradients: estimated using back-propagation
   # layer_dims: This is the list containing number of nodes in different hidden layers      
    vectorized_param = dictionary_to_vector(parameters)
    grads = gradient_to_vector(gradients)           
    num_parameters = vectorized_param.shape[0]
    J_plus = np.zeros((num_parameters,1))
    J_minus = np.zeros((num_parameters,1))
    GraDderive = np.zeros((num_parameters,1))   
    for i in range(num_parameters):
        print(i)
        vectorized_param_plus = np.copy(vectorized_param)
        vectorized_param_minus = np.copy(vectorized_param)
        vectorized_param_plus[i][0] = vectorized_param_plus[i][0]+ epsilon
        vectorized_param_minus[i][0] = vectorized_param_minus[i][0]- epsilon
        param_plus = vector_to_dictionary(vectorized_param_plus,layers_dims)
        param_minus = vector_to_dictionary(vectorized_param_minus,layers_dims)
        y_hat_plus, _= L_layer_forward_activation(X,param_plus)
        y_hat_minus, _= L_layer_forward_activation(X,param_minus)

        #J_plus[i] = cost_function(y_hat_plus, Y )
        #J_minus[i] = cost_function(y_hat_minus, Y )
        J_plus[i]  =  compute_cost_regularization(y_hat_plus,Y,param_plus,lmbda)
        J_minus[i] = compute_cost_regularization(y_hat_minus,Y,param_minus,lmbda)
        GraDderive[i] = np.divide((J_plus[i] - J_minus[i]), (2 * epsilon), dtype = np.float64)

    numerator = np.linalg.norm(GraDderive-grads)
    denominator = np.linalg.norm(grads) + np.linalg.norm(GraDderive)
    error =  np.divide(numerator, denominator, dtype = np.float64)

    if error > epsilon:
        print ("\033[93m" + "There is a mistake in the backward propagation! difference = " + str(error) + "\033[0m")
    else:
        print ("\033[92m" + "Your backward propagation works perfectly fine! difference = " + str(error) + "\033[0m")

    return error, GraDderive

def vector_to_dictionary(vector,layer_dims):
 #   Rhis function will convert vector into paramters
    L = len(layer_dims)
    init=0
    param={}
    for i in range(L-1):
        coeff_len = layer_dims[i + 1] * layer_dims[i]
        vec_len = init + coeff_len
        param["W" + str(i+1)] = vector[init : vec_len,0].reshape((layer_dims[i+1],layer_dims[i]))
        bias_len = vec_len+ layer_dims[i+1]
        param["b" + str(i+1)] = vector[vec_len:bias_len , 0].reshape((layer_dims[i+1],1))
        init = bias_len
    return param


def dictionary_to_vector(parameters):
#    This function will convert parameters dictionary to vectors
    L=len(parameters) // 2
    count=0
    #parameter_vector=[]

    for i in range(L):
        tempW = np.reshape(parameters["W" + str(i + 1)],(-1,1))
        tempb = np.reshape(parameters["b" + str(i + 1)],(-1,1))
        temp_theta = np.concatenate((tempW,tempb),axis=0)
        if count == 0:
            theta = temp_theta           
        else:
            theta = np.concatenate((theta,temp_theta), axis=0)
        count = count + 1

    return theta 

def gradient_to_vector(grads):
 #   This function will convert parameters dictionary to vectors
    L=len(grads) // 3
    count=0
    for i in range(L):
        tempW = np.reshape(grads["dW" + str(i + 1)],(-1,1))
        tempb = np.reshape(grads["db" + str(i + 1)],(-1,1))
        temp_theta = np.concatenate((tempW,tempb),axis=0)
        if count == 0:
            theta = temp_theta           
        else:
            theta = np.concatenate((theta,temp_theta), axis=0)
        count = count + 1

    return theta

def mini_batch(train_x, train_y,mini_batch_size):
    m = train_x.shape[1]
    num_complete_batch = math.floor(m / mini_batch_size)
    permutation = list(np.random.permutation(m))
    ShuffleX= train_x[:,permutation]
    ShuffleY= train_y[:,permutation]
    miniBatches=[]   
    for i in range(num_complete_batch):
        batchX = ShuffleX[:, (i * mini_batch_size):((i+1) * mini_batch_size)]
        batchY = ShuffleY[:,(i * mini_batch_size):((i+1) * mini_batch_size)]

        miniBatch =(batchX, batchY)
        miniBatches.append(miniBatch)
    if m % mini_batch_size !=0:
        batchX= ShuffleX[:,(m - m % mini_batch_size):m]
        batchY= ShuffleY[:,(m - m % mini_batch_size):m]
    miniBatch =(batchX, batchY)
    miniBatches.append(miniBatch)
    return miniBatches

def batch_normalization_forward(x, beta, gamma, epsilon):
    n, d = x.shape
    mu = np.mean(x, axis=1)
    sig = np.sqrt(np.var(x,axis =1))
    stand_x = (x - mu) / (sig + epsilon)
    beta_x = stand_x * beta
    gamma_x = beta_x + gamma
    return gamma_x

def prediction_error(y_hat,y):
    """y_hat is the prediction, y is the actual observation"""    
    y_hat = y_hat.reshape((y.shape[0],y.shape[1]))      
    error = np.sum(np.abs(y_hat-y))
    error_fraction = np.divide(error, y.shape[1]) * 100
    return error_fraction    

def layer_configuration(n_x,number_h,hidden_dimension,n_y):
    """The dimension of hidden layer"""
    layer_dim=[]
    layer_dim.append(n_x)
    for i in range(number_h):
        layer_dim.append(hidden_dimension[i])
    layer_dim.append(n_y)
    return layer_dim


#np.random.seed(1)
train_X, train_y, test_set_x_orig, test_set_y_orig, classes = load_dataset()
cost_list=[]
train_X_flatten = train_X.reshape(train_X.shape[0],-1).T
test_set_x_flatten = test_set_x_orig.reshape(test_set_x_orig.shape[0],-1).T
test_set_x_flatten= test_set_x_flatten/ 255
train_X_flatten = train_X_flatten / 255
#learning_rate = 0.007
GradienntCheck= True
lr0= 0.001                                                                     # initial learning rate
drop =0.5
epochs_drop = 10                                                               # drop the learning rate by half every 10 epochs
n_x = train_X_flatten.shape[0]                                                 # num_px * num_px * 3
n_hid_layer = 2
hidden_dimension= [2,2]
n_y = 1

layers_dims = layer_configuration(n_x,n_hid_layer,hidden_dimension,n_y)        #[n_x, n_h1, n_h2, n_h3, n_h4, n_h5, n_y]
number_of_iteration = 1000
epsilon= 1e-7                                                                  #grad check parameter
parameters = initalize_parameters(layers_dims)
s_momentum = initialize_s_momentum(parameters)
momentum = initialize_momentum(parameters)
algorithm = "1"
mini_batch_size = 128
learning_rate =lr0
lmbda =0.3
for epoch in range(number_of_iteration):    
    batch_data=mini_batch(train_X_flatten, train_y,mini_batch_size)
    for batch in batch_data:
        (batch_x , batch_y) = batch
        AL, caches = L_layer_forward_activation(batch_x, parameters)
        #cost_old = cost_function(AL,batch_y)
        cost =  compute_cost_regularization(AL,batch_y,parameters,lmbda)
        grad = L_backward_propagation(AL, batch_y,caches,lmbda)
        if algorithm == "Grad_momentum":
            parameters,_ = parameter_update_momentum(parameters,grad, momentum, learning_rate,0.9)        
        elif algorithm=="RMSprop":
            parameters,_ = RMS_prop_update(parameters, grad, momentum, learning_rate, 0.9)
        elif algorithm == "adam":
            parameters,_,_ = adam_algorithm(parameters, grad, momentum, s_momentum,learning_rate, 0.9, 0.999,(epoch + 1))        
        else:
            parameters = parameter_update(grad, learning_rate, parameters)    

        #if epoch==10:
            #difference, gradApprox = Gradient_check(batch_x, batch_y, parameters, grad, epsilon,layers_dims)
         #   difference, gradApprox = Gradient_check(batch_x, batch_y, parameters, grad, epsilon,layers_dims, lmbda)
          #  sys.exit()
          #  break

        cost_list.append(cost)
    #learning_rate = np.power(0.95, epoch) * learning_rate                                 #exponentially decaying learning rate
    learning_rate = lr0 * drop**math.floor(epoch / epochs_drop) 
    if(epoch % 100==0):
        print(" The cost of network at epoch: % d/%d is  : %f " %(epoch, number_of_iteration,cost))

##########################
perm = list(np.random.permutation(test_set_x_flatten.shape[1]))
dev_perm = perm[0:len(perm)//2]
test_perm =list(set(perm)- set(dev_perm))
##################################
dev_x = test_set_x_flatten[:,dev_perm]
test_x = test_set_x_flatten[:,test_perm]
dev_y =  test_set_y_orig[:,dev_perm]
test_y = test_set_y_orig[:,test_perm]
########################################
y_hat_training = predict(train_X_flatten,parameters)
y_hat_dev = predict(dev_x,parameters)
y_hat_test = predict(test_x,parameters)
 ####################################################
trainin_error_rate = prediction_error(y_hat_training,train_y)
dev_error_rate = prediction_error(y_hat_dev,dev_y)
test_error_rate = prediction_error(y_hat_test,test_y)

print("The training set error on the data is:"+ str(trainin_error_rate))
print("The dev set error is:"+ str(dev_error_rate))
print("The test set error is:" + str(test_error_rate))
```